# Facebook login button not triggered when clicked in my external site

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

i'm using facebook javascript sdk i've placed a log in button  when user clicks the button below function will execute.and i verified that the all.js loaded successfully but some times it wont.

```
    <div id="divFBloginbtn" style="display: block;">
<div id="fb-root"> </div>
<fb:login-button onlogin="getPages()" style="opacity: .01 !important; width: 250px !important; line-height: 31px !important; margin-top: 0 !important;" size="large" scope="manage_pages,offline_access,read_insights"> Sign In With Facebook Account </fb:login-button>
</div>
</div>
```

please some on help me to figure out the problem

Answer (score 0):

If the user is already logged in, nothing will happen when the button is clicked. Try logging off facebook and try again, or even better, use your browser's incognito mode.

Comment: it triggers now  its my fault  i've added the all.js twice that is the problem but, the problem turned out to be serious now because its shows  This webpage is not available now in the pop up, i tried in the developers.facebook.com in this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/   it showed the same....

Comment: thanks for spending your valuable time for me, in the above link i checked twice still its shows that webpage not available will you please figure out what went wrong.. its facebook domain problem or its happening only for me .. thanks in advance